# PHP recursive loops sequence not followed

Tags: php, html, loops

I had an assignment to make a md5 crack of a four character string using brute-force algorithm. The program takes md5 hash as input and outputs the four digit string corresponding to the hash ([can be calculated from here](https://www.wa4e.com/solutions/crack/makepin.php)).

Below is my PHP source code. (Built on top of already provided sample)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
  <title>Charles Severance MD5 Cracker</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>MD5 cracker</h1>
  <p>This application takes an MD5 hash of a four digit pin as string and attempts to hash all combinations to determine the original pin.</p>
  <pre>
Debug Output:
<?php
$goodtext = "Not found";
// This is our alphabet
$txt = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ,./;'[]\\-=<>?:\"{}|_+`~!@#$%^&*()";  // all possible combinations
$show=100;
// If there is no parameter, this code is all skipped
if ( isset($_GET['md5']) ) {
    $time_pre = microtime(true);
    $md5 = $_GET['md5'];
    $noOfchecks=0;
    for($i=0; $i<strlen($txt); $i++ ) {
        for($j=0; $j<strlen($txt); $j++ ) {
            for($k=0; $k<strlen($txt); $k++ ) {
                for($l=0; $l<strlen($txt); $l++ ) {
                    $ch1 = $txt[$i];   // The first of four characters 
                    $ch2 = $txt[$j];  // Our second character
                    $ch3 = $txt[$k];  // Our third character
                    $ch4 = $txt[$l];  // Our fourth character

                    $try = $ch1.$ch2.$ch3.$ch4;
                    // Run the hash and then check to see if we match
                    $check = hash('md5', $try);
                    $noOfchecks++;
                    if ( $check == $md5 ) {
                        $goodtext = $try;
                        break;   // Exit the loop
                    }
                    // Debug output until $show hits 0
                    if ( $show > 0 ) 
                    {
                        print "$check $try\n";
                        $show = $show - 1;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    // Compute elapsed time
    $time_post = microtime(true);
    
    print "Total Checks: ";
    print $noOfchecks;
    print "\n";
    print "Elapsed time: ";
    print $time_post-$time_pre;
    print "\n";
}
?>
</pre>
  <!-- Use the very short syntax and call htmlentities() -->
  <p>Original Text:
    <?= htmlentities($goodtext); ?>
  </p>
  <form>
    <input type="text" name="md5" size="60" />
    <input type="submit" value="Crack MD5" />
  </form>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="index.php">Reset</a></li>
    <li><a href="md5.php">MD5 Encoder</a></li>
    <li><a href="makecode.php">MD5 Code Maker</a></li>
    <li><a href="https://github.com/csev/wa4e/tree/master/code/crack" target="_blank">Source code for this application</a></li>
  </ul>
</body>

</html>
```

The program starts from 0000, calculates its md5 hash and compares it with provided hash and if they are equal, it exits and returns the four character string otherwise moves on to 0001 and so on (till whole *$txt* string is tried). Additionally, for debugging, it outputs the first 100 strings for which it computed hash and compared with user input hash.

Now coming to problem I am facing, when I input the hash of 0000 i.e.

> 4a7d1ed414474e4033ac29ccb8653d9b

It starts its computation from 0010 [image: shown using the debugged output] as shown above and reaches 0000 after 58 seconds. (which should not happen as it should compute for 0000 first and return immediately). Similarly, if I provide hash value of

> fc1198178c3594bfdda3ca2996eb65cb

which is for number 0010, it starts from 0000 and reaches 0010 after again 50+ seconds (and it does skip 0010 as per sequence and comes back to it after 50+ secs.)

Start at 0000 Now
[image]

Skipping of 0010 and moving to 0020 instead

[image]

**Why is my program changing computation order based on input**, when it is clearly defined in my loop initialization i.e. 0000.

I am using XAMPP with MAX_EXECUTION_TIME=100 in php.ini (to avoid timeouts). The browser is Google Chrome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your debugging code only prints when the hash doesn't match. Since you entered the hash for `0000`, it finds the match on the first attempt, and doesn't print that.

The `break` statement by default only breaks out of the closest loop. So when you find a match, you break out of the loop that's incrementing the last digit, but continues the other loops. So when it matches `0000`, it goes to the next iteration of the `$k` loop, and tries next with `0010`.

You should break out of all the loops when you find the match. You can use `break 4` to break out of 4 levels of loop, but a better way would be to move the loops into a function and use `return $try;` to return the value that was found. Returning from a function terminates all the loops.

Comment: Took me 3+ hours to find the problem. Wish I could add breakpoints... Anyways Thanks a lot